# SQL silently converts int to varchar, but then throws an error when it comes across a varchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I came across an issue in a SQL script recently, where an insert statement (that was inserting multiple rows) had a column of type varchar(10) and the rows of data it was inserting were passing in ints.

However, when I added a new row of data to insert, and used a varchar in the varchar column, SQL tried to convert it to an int, even though the column is of type varchar(10)

Here's an example you can run locally.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable
    (
    VarcharColumn varchar(10) NOT NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]

insert into TestTable(VarcharColumn)
Values (1)
```

When you run this, it inserts just fine, SQL must silently convert that integer value into a varchar behind the scenes.

However then if you try this:

```
insert into TestTable(VarcharColumn)
Values (1),(2),('Hello')
```

SQL will throw the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Hello' to data
>   type int.

Can anybody offer an explanation into the inner workings of SQL in this case? Specifically:

1. Why SQL allows you to insert integers into varchar columns
2. Why when SQL is silently converting these values, if it runs across an actual varchar it will try to convert it to int.

I understand how to fix this issue and how to avoid it in the first place, but I am looking for an explanation as to why SQL works this way.

Comment: go through the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx)

Comment: What is to explain?  Your questions show that you understand the situation exactly how it is.  The answer is:  That is how SQL Server works.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that is not what I asked. I asked two questions, one as to why it allows implicit conversion (which vkp's link to the documentation seems to explain) and how the implicit conversion works in insert statements with multiple rows. "That's just how it works" is an awful, nothing statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what happened. When SQL Server ran, it went through the rows

```
 (1),(2),('Hello')
```

and realized that there are more than one data type there. Hence it converted it to the one with the highest precedence (int vs varchar).

That is why you got the error.

See more about Data Type Precedence here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think you're right. I edited the answer.

Comment: . . I think it determines the types during compilation.  It might generate the error in compilation; it might generate the error during run-time.  If you know its a compilation error then the description is fine.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried running a test with INSERT ... VALUES (1),(2). I got the query plan (from right to left) of Constant Scan -> Compute Scalar -> Table Insert -> INSERT. So I guess the Constant Scan was executed first, converting everything to int, then, the Table Insert convert int to varchar.

Comment: Well written, I actually just tried to run a similar statement insert into TestTable(VarcharColumn)
Values ('hello'),(2),('15') 

and it (as you said) finds int as the highest precendence and trys to convert all values to it. '15' is valid in this case, but the 'hello' isn't. Thanks for explaining this!

Comment: @DotNetNF Thanks for asking. I was able to clarify my thought more trying to write this down (hence understand it better).